# what is the opencv code flow for the resize function using bicubic c++?

Tags: c++, opencv, resize

I am trying to understand the resize function from opencv 4.0, and when I use bilinear I can follow the code which happens in resize.cpp hal::resize , (modules/imgproc/src). But when I change for bicubic, it does not follow the same flow (even the code having conditionals for INTER_CUBIC). I set breakpoints using gdb inside hal::resize , and for bicubic it does not reach the breakpoint.

I am trying to find out where the code is running , which part is being executed.

when I debug I can see the data for bilinear and lanczos , but not bicubic ! But I am presuming it might a gdb issue , the data is: Resize.cpp
for linear : at the end of hal::resize.cpp:3706

````
$1 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12}
(gdb) p yofs[0]@10
$2 = {0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13}
(gdb) p ialpha[0]@10
$3 = {1536, 512, 1536, 512, 1536, 512, 512, 1536, 512, 1536}
(gdb) p ibeta[0]@10
$4 = {1536, 512, 512, 1536, 1536, 512, 512, 1536, 1536, 512}
(gdb) 

for lanczos
(gdb) p xofs[0]@10
$5 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12}
(gdb) p yofs[0]@10
$6 = {0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13}
(gdb) p ialpha[0]@10
$7 = {-31, 114, -312, 1830, 579, -188, 64, -8, -31, 114}
(gdb) p ibeta[0]@10
$8 = {-31, 114, -312, 1830, 579, -188, 64, -8, -8, 64}```
````

Answer (score 0):

ok, 
I guess it was an opencv compilation issue, I just set WITH_IPP OFF plus the other multithreads flags off, to guarantee that I am using single thread only, and I enabled ENABLE_PROFILING=ON , besides being Debug mode in the configuration file. Now it is showing data of bicubic.

cmake -D WITH_TBB=OFF -D WITH_OPENMP=OFF -D WITH_IPP=OFF -D ENABLE_PROFILING=ON -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -D WITH_NVCUVID=OFF -D WITH_CUDA=OFF